# Is the definition given by the GAP-manual equivalent to the one given in the site?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Here

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normalizer_of_a_subset_of_a_group

the normalizer of a subset of a group is defined.

GAP gives the following description of the Function IsNormal :

39.3.6 IsNormal
. IsNormal(G, U) (operation)
returns true if the group G normalizes the group U and false otherwise.
A group G normalizes a group U if and only if for every $g\in G$ and $u \in U$ the element $u^g$ is a
member of U. Note that U need not be a subgroup of G.
Example
gap> IsNormal(g,u);
false

> 1) What does u^g mean (g is a group, so normally does not have integer entries) ?
>
> 2) If U is a subgroup of G, does IsNormal(G,U) always correctly decide whether U is a normal subgroup of G ?

Comment: Why the close-vote ? I asked the question clearly and showed where I got stuck. And the question can surely be answered. If someone means the question can be improved, he/she should do it instead of voting for a close.

Comment: I agree, I do not see any reason to close this question.

Comment: $u^g = gug^{-1}$, and so this is equivalent to the condition that $N$ is normal when $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Thanks. So, if $U$ is a subgroup  of $G$ (not only a subset) the command simply decides whether $U$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, right ?

Comment: Yup, though it sounds like you'll have to check that $U$ is a subgroup separately.

Comment: But the question isn't about mathematics, it is about the syntax of a computer algebra system.

Comment: Also, $u^g$ in GAP means $g^{-1}ug$, not $gug^{-1}$, and remember that GAP composes permutations from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation is conjugation; $u^g = gug^{-1}$. The one of the definitions of a normal subgroup:
$$N \trianglelefteq G \Leftrightarrow gNg^{-1} \subseteq N \Leftrightarrow gng^{-1} \in N\ \ \ \forall n \in N, g\in G$$

So as long as you verify that $U$ really is a subgroup, that test should tell you if it is normal or not. So you want to run something like

```
IsNormal(G,H) and IsSubgroup(G,H);
```

which outputs true if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and false otherwise.